# Is neo4j GPG key expired?

Tags: neo4j

from apt-get update:

```
  The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 26C95CF201182252 Neo Technology Admins <admins@neotechnology.com>  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1572135620
Fetched 328 kB in 0s (339 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/ Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 26C95CF201182252 Neo Technology Admins <admins@neotechnology.com>  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1572135620
W: Failed to fetch https://debian.neo4j.org/repo/stable/Release.gpg  The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 26C95CF201182252 Neo Technology Admins <admins@neotechnology.com>  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1572135620
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

apt-key list:

```
# apt-key list 01182252
pub   4096R/01182252 2014-10-28 [expired: 2019-10-27]
uid                  Neo Technology Admins <admins@neotechnology.com>
```

I use https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key to fetch the key

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The key is now updated. You can redo:

`wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.com/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -`

or to update the apt keys list from the keyserver:

`sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net  D37F5F19 01182252`